# Contraction Mapping Theorem. Prove $\{ y_{1},f(y_{1}),f(f(y_{1})),\ \ldots) \} $ is Cauchy. (Abbott p 114 q4.3.9b)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function defined on all of $R$. Assume there is a constant $c$ such that $0< c <1$ and $ |f(x)\ -f(y)\leq c|x-y|$ for all $x,\ y\in R$.

(a) Show that $f$ is continuous on $R$ for all $c \in R$.

(b) Pick some point $y_{1}\in R$ and construct the sequence $ (y_{1},f(y_{1}),f(f(y_{1})),\ \ldots)\ $
In general, if $y_{n+1}=f(y_{n})$ , show that the resulting sequence $(y_{n})$ is  Cauchy. Hence let $y=\displaystyle \lim y_{n}$.

**Solution** (b) Observe that for any fixed $n\in N$, $|y_{m+1}-y_{m+2}|=|f(y_m) - f(y_{m + 1})| \leq c|y_{m}-y_{m+1}|. $ This idea can be extended inductively to conclude that

$\begin{align} |y_{m+1}-y_{m+2}| & \leq c|y_{m}-y_{m+1}|
\\ & \leq c^2|y_{m-1}-y_{m}|
 \\ & \leq ... \leq c^{m}|y_{1}-y_{2}| \end{align}$.

> **1.** Why start with $|y_{m+1}-y_{m+2}|$?
>
> **2.** Intuitively, how do we know $|y_{m+1}-y_{m+2}| \le ... \le c^{m}...|y_{1}-y_{2}|$?
>   From $|y_{m+1}-y_{m+2}|$ to  $...|y_{1}-y_{2}|$, how do we know we need $c^m$ and not c^{another exponent}? Not questioning about proofs or rigour in this question 2.

$0 <c<1$ implies $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c^{n}$ converges. This will invoke $(y_{n})$ is Cauchy. How? Note for $m <n$:

> $3.$ Why need $m < n$? What does this signify?

[image]

> **4.** What's the modus operandi  of all these (fey) steps? I know the first inequality is Triangle Inequality and the second is my question 2. But how to presage to do this?
>
> $5.$ Geometric series formula engenders $1 + c + .. + c^{\color{magenta}{n - m} - 1} = \dfrac{1(1 - c^{\color{magenta}{n - m}})}{1 - c}$.  Why $1/(1 - c)$?

Let $\epsilon >0$, and choose $N\in \mathbb{N}$ large enough so that $c^{\color{red}{N} - 1}|y_1 - y_2| \dfrac{1}{1 - c}< \epsilon$.

> **6.** Don't we want the RHS term in $\color{magenta}{♫} < \epsilon$? So the red $c^{\color{red}{N} - 1}$ should be $c^{m - 1}$?

Then the overhead shows: $n>m\geq N$ implies $|y_{m}-y_{n}|<\epsilon$. This $\iff (y_{n})$ is Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to 1. is simply "Why not?" You could start with $|y_{m}-y_{m-1}|$ as well, that would not change the proof significantly, but it would change the occuring exponents of $c$ by some additive constant.

@2: The inequality $|y_{m+1}-y_{m+2}|\leq c^m |y_1-y_2|$ follows by $m$ applications of the assumption. Note that $y_{m+1} = f(y_m)$, $y_{m+2}=f(y_{m+1})$ and so on. Therefore in every of the $m$ steps you have the distance between two values of $f$ and the assumption lets you bound that distance by $c$ times the distance between the two preimages. Doing this $m$ times produces $m$ factors of $c$ and the constant $|y_1-y_2|$. (And that is also why it doesn't matter if you start with $y_{m+1}$ or $y_{m+15}$: just apply the same reasoning 15 times more, get another 15 in the exponent and carry on with the rest of the proof)

@3: This does not signify anything. Note that $|y_n-y_m|=|y_m-y_n|$ so one can assume $m\leq n$ wlog. And the case $n=m$ is trivial because the distance is zero in that case and certainly bounded by whatever positive term we will deduce.

@4: There is not much more to that then what you already mentioned. The first step is repeated application of the triangle inequality, the second is application of the prior estimate, the last one is application of the geometric series.

@5: The partial sum $1+c+c^2+\ldots+c^{n-m}$ is bounded by the infinite series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c^k=\frac{1}{1-c}$ because $c>0$. You could bound it by the partial sum, but that would leave the term $c^{n-m+1}$ in which needlessly complicated the expression. We slightly less precise but otherwise simpler bound is sufficient for the argument.

@6: No, we want the RHS to be less than $\epsilon$ **for all $m,n\geq N$**, not just for some particular numbers $n,m$. Therefore we have to ensure that the RHS is small for all (sufficiently big) $n,m$. Note that $c^{m-1} \leq c^{N-1}$ for all $m\geq N$ because of $0<c<1$.