# Contraction Mapping Theorem. Any $\{ x,f(x),f(f(x)),\ \ldots) \} $ converges to the unique fixed point of f. (Abbott p 114 q4.3.9 d)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be a function defined on all of $R$. Assume there is a constant $c$ such that $0< c <1$ and $ |f(x)\ -f(y)\leq c|x-y|$ for all $x,\ y\in R$. [Parts a,b](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/779745/85079).

(c) Prove that $y$ is a fixed point of $f (i.e.,\ f(y)=y)$ and that it is unique in this regard.

(d) Finally, prove that if $x$ is any arbitrary point in $R$, then the sequence $(x,\ f(x),\ f(f(x)),\ \ldots)$ converges to $y$ defined in (b).

The argument in (b) and (c) applies to any sequence of iterates. Thus, given an arbitrary x, we assert that $(x,\ f(x),\ f(f(x)),\ \ldots)$ converges to a limit $x'$ and that $x'$ is a fixed point of $f$. But $y$ is also a fixed point and so $ |f(x')-f(y)|=|x^{l}-y|. $
However, $f(x')- f(y)| \leq c|x' - y|$ must also be true.
And because 0 < c < 1, x' = y.

> **1.** What's y in part (d)? Why is it also a fixed point? Part (d) didn't posit y?
>
> **2.** Why $x' = y$? How do the last 2e and 3e lines engender this?

Comment: "What's y in part (d)?" **The point y was defined in part (b)**. For the reader who forgot this, they even take pain to recall it: "converges to y defined in (b)". Sorry but what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

1st question: $y$ is the limit of the sequence $x_n=f^n(x)$ ($f$ applied $n$ times to $x$)

$y$ Is also the fixed point of the map $f$, and the sequence converges to this point because $f$ is a contraction.

2nd question: Because we get from this $|x'-y|\lt |x'-y|$ and the only way this can hold is if $x'=y$

Answer (score 0):

1. Let $f^n(x)$ be $f$ applied to $x$ $n$ times. $y$ is the same $y$ as defined in part b. We see that:

$|f^n(x)-f^n(y)| \le c|f^{n-1}(x) - f^{n-1}y| \le c^n|x-y|$

and therefore,

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} |f^n(x)-f^n(y)|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} |f^n(x)-y| \to 0$.

However, $\{f^n(x)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, therefore it converges to some $x^{\prime}$, and by the same argument as you made in part c, this $x^{\prime}$ is a fixed point of $f$.

2.From the estimates above, we see that $x^{\prime}=y$.